# Generating set of an infinite group

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Must a generating set for a group of infinite order be finite?

E.g $\{1\}$ is a finite generating set for $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: No. Free group on the generators $x_1,x_2,\cdots$.

Comment: No. For  example  $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$.  For  more  non-trivial  examples , there   are  $\mathbb Q/ \mathbb Z$, the group $\mathbb G$=$\{z\in \mathbb C |z^{n}=1,n\in \mathbb N \}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on one generator.  A free group is completely determined by its generating set, which can be any set.  So we can consider a free group on an infinite number of generators as a counterexample.

For a more concrete example consider $(\mathbb{R},+)$.  If this were finitely generated then we would have $|\mathbb{R}|\leq|x_1\mathbb{Z}|\cdot|x_2\mathbb{Z}|\cdots|x_n\mathbb{Z}|$.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: @MattSamuel I have corrected my post.  In this case we can view $(\mathbb{R},+)$ as a quotient of a free abelian group. Any free abelian group on $n$ generators is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ which has a strictly lower cardinality.